# Get member data from a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am reading a .csv file using multiple threads. Each thread reads a part of the .csv file, eg. thread1 reads from `line:214` to `line:359`.

```
CSVReader reader1("C:\\file.csv", 214, 359);
```

During reading process, the data fields are stored in a vector instance.

```
data[i].push_back(data_field);
```

In main function, the codes are like below:

```
CSVReader reader1("C:\\file.csv", 214, 359);
CSVReader reader2("C:\\file.csv", 360, 517);

thread t1(&CSVReader::read_range, reader1);
thread t2(&CSVReader::read_range, reader2);

t1.join();
t2.join();

vector<vector<string>> temp_data = reader1.get_data();  // Here I have the problem
```

Ideally, `reader1.get_data()` should return the data between `line:214` and `line:359`. But when I look into `temp_data`, I found it is not changed at all.

May I know what am I wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to refine your question. You ask for temp_data where this is not described anywhere. When you push_back some data you would need synchronization, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the threads you pass *copies* of `reader1` and `reader2`, so the copies are modified not the original objects. That means the data are added to the copies, and the original objects are unchanged.  To pass them by reference use `std::ref(reader1)` and `std::ref(reader2)`.

If your `CSVReader::read_range` function takes a reference your code should not compile, but some buggy compilers (including Visual C++) accept it.

(N.B. in general you should have shown the definition or at least the signature of `CSVReader::read_range` so people don't have to guess what your code does.)

Comment: Hi, Jonathan. Thank you very much for your answer. The problem is solved now with your solution. Many thanks again.